# Remove date from movie filenames recursively without using rename

Tags: rename

I have a directory "Movies" with individual directories like, "Gone with the Wind" and filenames like, "Gone with the Wind (1939).mp4

I want to rename them, removing the " (1939)" portion, so the result is "Gone with the Wind.mp4"

On osx, I can do this with rename, something like this:

`rename 's/ \(.*?\)//' *.mp4`

How can this be done without using rename?

Comment: If that's one of the two standard `rename` commands (it looks like the `perl` one), it should not be copying the file

Comment: No, `rename` doesn't copy files. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Show us `type -a rename`.

Comment: It is [this rename command](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) (perl).

Comment: @waltinator "rename is /usr/local/bin/rename"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be on macos, your shell is likely `zsh`, so you should be able to do:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '(**/)(*)[[:space:]]##\(<1800-2022>\)(.mp4)' '$1$2$3'
```

(remove the  `-n` for *dry-run* if happy, replace `<1800-2022>` with `[0-9](#c4)` for any 4 digits instead of a range of numbers).

Instead of using `rename`.

`zmv`, like `perl`'s `rename` *renames* files, it doesn't copy them¹, though while `rename` uses the `rename()` perl function which calls the `rename()` system call underneath, `zmv` just calls `mv` which will call `rename()` as well as long as source and target are on the same filesystem.

---

<sup>¹ you can use the `-C` option of `zmv` though to use `cp` instead of `mv`</sup>

Comment: Yes macos, but bash is default... I tested with zsh. Your solution is not recursive but will rename properly if run in the movie folder.

Comment: @lilbiscuit, sorry I had missed the *recursive* part of the requirements. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

The `rename` command does not copy files:

```
touch 'Gone with the Wind (1939).mp4'

ls -li Gone*.mp4
129371 -rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 0 Dec 14 14:33 Gone with the Wind (1939).mp4

rename 's/\s*\(\d{4}\)//' Gone*.mp4

ls -li Gone*.mp4
129371 -rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 0 Dec 14 14:33 Gone with the Wind.mp4
```

The inode number remains the same, demonstrating that it's still the same file

Comment: Finder? Oh, so you're on a Mac @lilbiscuit. Where did you get your `rename` from? I'll see if I can install the same tool

Comment: I have not been able to recreate copying. It's possible pilot error where file was still  being copied prior to executing "rename".